# What is the relation between software and hardware ports?

Tags: transport-protocol, interface

> A port number is a 16-bit unsigned integer, thus ranging from 0 to
> 65535

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)

And I think computers have small number of hardware interfaces(ports) for network communications, so what is the relation between hardware and software ports. Like HTTP by default will run on port 80, so does that mean it will run on hardware port 80?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no relation (or only a *very* distant one).

A hardware interface attaches a network to a host (or devices like switches or router). It belongs to the physical layer (OSI layer 1).

A port number in a transport-layer protocol (OSI layer 4) serves as a subaddress on a host - that way, you can run multiple, independent applications on a host. Each subaddress/port allows you to address an application/a process on a host instead of the host as a whole (roughly). Without L4 ports, you couldn't run FTP, HTTP, SSH, SMTP, ... all on a single server and only one application on your computer could access the network or Internet at a time.

From the network theory perspective, a *hardware interface* (physical layer L1) is multiplexed by using e.g. MAC addresses and VLANs in the data link layer (L2). That in turn is multiplexed by using e.g. IP addresses in the network layer (L3). That in turn is multiplexed using transport-layer protocols like TCP or UDP (L4). Many of those are then multiplexed using *port numbers*.

Answer (score 0):

> A hardware interface attaches a network to a host (or devices like switches or router). It belongs to the physical layer (OSI layer 1).

Some addition about ports in general terms - it can be any type of connection, not only network. The simple examples are printers and scanners, which can be connected as ports - via hardware interface (parallel port with a 36-pin jack) and by corresponding software (for example, LPT1 port) as component to be used by OS and/or applications. Regarding port numbering for software references - the [LPT1 uses PC ports 378h to 37Bh](https://redirect.cs.umbc.edu/courses/undergraduate/CMSC211/fall02/burt/lectures/CntlHardware/printers.html).
The traditional hardware ports can be serials or parallel, uni- or bidirectional, etc.